# C# 7.2 use of "in parameter" for operators

Tags: c#, operators, c#-7.2, in-parameters

In C# 7.2, we saw the introduction of the `in` modifier for method parameters to pass read-only references to objects. I'm working on a new .NET Standard project using 7.2, and out of curiosity I tried compiling with the `in` keyword on the parameters for the equality operators for a struct.

i.e.  -  `public static bool operator == (in Point l, in Point r)`

not   -  `public static bool operator == (Point l, Point r)`

I was initially a bit surprised that this worked, but after thinking about it a bit I realized that there is probably no functional difference between the two versions of the operator. I wanted to confirm these suspicions, but after a somewhat thorough search around, I can't find anything that explicitly talks about using the `in` keyword in operator overloads.

So my question is whether or not this actually has a functional difference, and if it does, is there any particular reason to encourage or discourage the use of `in` with operator arguments. My initial thoughts are that there is no difference, particularly if the operator is inlined. However, if it does make a difference, it seems like in parameters should be used everywhere (*everywhere that readonly references make sense, that is*), as they provide a speed bonus, and, unlike `ref` and `out`, don't require the user to prepend the those keywords when passing objects. This would allow more efficient value-type object passing without a single change on the user of the methods and operators.

Overall, this may go beyond the sort of small-scale optimizations that most C# developers worry about, but I am curious as to whether or not it has an effect.

Comment: `Point` is a value type, so `in` doesn't really make any difference here.

Comment: Is this because operators are generally inlined? Because normally this would make the difference of passing by reference instead of value.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `in` is almost exclusively useful for value types.  What makes you think that `in` is pointless when used with value types.

Comment: @SeanM. You appear to overestimate the benefits of passing a value by reference.  Unless the value type is particularly large, someone else is mutating it *and you actually want to observe those mutations*, there isn't much to be gained.  If your structs are well designed, that is to say, they are not significantly larger than the size of a reference, then passing through the reference will be comparable to copying the value.  It's really only a win for poorly designed value types (or the very rare cases that are an exception to those guidelines).

Comment: I guess the guidelines are exactly the same as for regular methods: if the struct is sufficiently large then it makes sense to use "in". What "sufficiently large" means is another question.

Comment: I understand that `Point` (which in my case is just two `Int32`s) is probably a bad example, its just what I initially used in my code so I just copy/pasted it. In the case where the value types are significantly larger than the reference size, this would have more of an effect. I am more curious about the effects it would have in operators in general, if different from methods, due to the effects of inlining or other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

> whether or not this actually has a functional difference... My initial thoughts are that there is no difference, particularly if the operator is inlined

Since the operator `==` overload is invoked like a regular static method in `MSIL`, it has the functional difference. It can help to avoid unnecessary copying like in a regular method.

> is there any particular reason to encourage or discourage the use of in with operator arguments.

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code#apply-the-in-modifier-to-readonly-struct-parameters-larger-than-systemintptrsize) it is recommended to apply `in` modifier when value types are larger than `System.IntPtr.Size`. But it is important that the value type should be  **`readonly struct`**. Otherwise `in` modifier can harm the performance because the compiler will create a defensive copy when calling struct's methods and properties since they can change the state of the argument.